# Toggle switch presentation in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, input, microsoft-edge

I've coded some toggle switches just using CSS (no JS). When previewing them via the Microsoft Explorer programme they come out as the default checkboxes.

I've applied these styles:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

to the CSS file, however I've been reading that Microsoft Edge doesn't "play by" the WebKit features.

Is there any way around this at all?

```css
.toggle-switch{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 4em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 3em;
    background-color: #DED;
    transform: backgrond-color 0.09s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-switch:checked{
    background: #0D0155;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-switch::after{
    content: "";
    width: 2em;
    height:2em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    left: 0;
    transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.toggle-switch:checked::after{
    left: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-switch" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-switch">
```

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

What is previews as:

[image: What it previews as]

Comment: `however I've been reading that Microsoft Edge doesn't "play by" the WebKit features` This is incorrect. Microsoft Edge supports WebKit prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to style a `label` instead of styling the `input` and hide the `input`. Indeed, you can use the `for` attribute on the `label` to refer to the `input`, so that when you click on it, it toggles the checkbox. Then you won't have any more problems with checkboxes appearing because your `input` will be in `display: none`.

Here is an example:

```css
.checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-switch {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  background-color: #DED;
  transition: background-color 0.09s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox:checked + .toggle-switch {
  background: #0D0155;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-switch::after{
  content: "";
  width: 2em;
  height:2em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.checkbox:checked + .toggle-switch::after{
  left: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox-id" checked>
<label class="toggle-switch" for="checkbox-id"></label>
```